# __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'creator'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am getting type error while setting current user to created_by field in my model

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('name',)

        def __init__(self, *args, creator, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.creator = creator

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.instance.created_by = self.creator
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatEEView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView,):
    form_class =  ''
    template_name = ''
    success_url = ''
```

**Models.py**

```
class MYmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey()
```

Comment: The error makes complete sense it mans it requires `creator` to be passed with `super().__int__(*args,creator,**kwargs)` but where you have defined creator? Can you also share your Model? And its very bad practice that you have named your `Model` as `Model`, don't do that, it clashes, and also don't give any field name in model as `save,delete` etc. it also clashes, read the docs.

Comment: @SunderamDubey its for stack i renamed them and i have already shared model brother please take a look

Comment: please edit your question with current code, don't renamed them. Sorry, i haven't seen the model.

Comment: bro u can see all the necessary code they are just attributes and template names and form_class(which is already mentioned) i have just removed the names that's this is all the code

Comment: and Model.py file in bold

Comment: So, what is `,` in `CreateEView` at the end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244282/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-mikan).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a custom form for that because CreateView is creating ModelForm for you, what you can do is like that:

```
from django.db import models

class MYmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey()
```

Then you can override the form_valid method. This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import MYmodel

class CreatEEView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = MYmodel
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You can find the same example in Django documents in this [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Comment: Thanks for the answer i already know this but i do not want the logic to be in view it should only be in form

Comment: Then you can override the get_form_kwargs methode inside your view like this

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CreatEEView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'my_var': 'my value'})
    return kwargs

Comment: so here my_var will be created_by and my value = self.request.user is it? and what in form

Comment: @mikan: no `'creator'`. But it is bad code design: a form should only be concerned with cleaning and validating user input. Especially since that form is likely later also reused to edit data, and then could by accident use a different user...

Comment: I want my views to look cleaner want logic to be in forms or models as Two scoops book suggests so how else can i do

Comment: @mikan: well now you add custom logic to the form *and* to the view, and you make the form less reusable... The only sensical way is to do this in the view.

Comment: @mikan: this is also how the documentation specifies to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user